# cast text field to array in mysql select query

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, select

I have a table in MySQL database. In that table there is a text field called 'selection' that hold numbered values, separated by a pipe char (example: 44|5|23|546|.....). I also have a php array: $values = array(63,35,7,5);

I need to refer to the 'selection' field as array of options (separated by '|') and select only the rows that contain at least one of the number in $values array.

I hope i explained my problem accurately enough, because my English is very poor... Thanks.

Comment: I would argue that the _actual_ problem is that the database design isn't storing relational elements as distinct pieces of data.  Why not split out that pipe-delimited field into a separate table?  Querying it would become a lot easier, since SQL is designed to query relational tables.

Comment: The problem is that a field usually contain only one value. Not multiple values. If you need to have multiple values on one field, you should have a table with a relation (a many-to-many relation). See here for more details: http://www.tomjewett.com/dbdesign/dbdesign.php?page=manymany.php

Comment: That is a strong point, and i will change this logic if I couldn't fined more simple solution for this. Changing the structure of the db will cost me a lot of time and i'm a bit lazy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to get row that contains at least one number in `$values` array, the SQL looks like this:

```
$values = array(63,35,7,5);

foreach ($values as $value) {

     $sql = "select * from tablename where selection like '%{$value}|%' or '%|{$value}%'";

}
```

Comment: This would fail when searching for '2' and there's `12|13` in the field. you need 4 cases for this kinda of bad design. 1) straight equality (one value), value at start (`$v|%`), value at end (`%|$v`) and value in middle (`%|$v|%`).

Comment: @MarcB - If you could add this in a separated answer i could mark it as accepted. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

If the values in the array are in the appropriate order for search already, you can build your query with something like this:

```
$selection_searched = implode('|', $values);
$query = "SELECT * FROM your_table WHERE selection = '$selection_searched'";
```

Beware that you would probably want to validate the array $values fisrt, to check if it isn't empty, etc. Check out the manual for: http://php.net/implode

Comment: will not work: `SELECT  '4|3|5|' =  '4|5|3|'` values in field are not sorted in any specific way

Comment: Then maybe you should change your model, putting the fields in another table.